# How to avoid Premiere to YouTube upload errors?

Tags: premiere, youtube

When I try to publish videos from Premiere to YouTube, I get this error:

```
02/24/2016 01:20:41 PM : YouTube({
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.video",
    "reason": "invalidDescription",
    "message": "The request metadata specifies an invalid video description.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "body.snippet.description"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The request metadata specifies an invalid video description."
 }
}
) - {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.video",
    "reason": "invalidDescription",
    "message": "The request metadata specifies an invalid video description.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "body.snippet.description"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The request metadata specifies an invalid video description."
 }
}
```

I've encountered a similar error from both FCPX and Premiere when my title is too long (over 70 characters).  I'm wondering what the rules are for a YouTube description.  I've read that the max character length is 5000, but I didn't find that on an official YouTube page, so I'm not sure.  Plus, my description text is way less than 5000 characters, so It must be something else.  I've tried eliminating most special characters (everything but spaces, periods, minus signs, and capital letters), but I'm still getting this error.

Can anyone point me to an official list of requirements for the title text and description text of YouTube videos?

This is an especially frustrating problem because neither Premiere nor FCPX will warn against these errors before rendering out video.  They'll happily churn away for an hour or more, try to upload, then poop themselves.

*edit*

A few people have recommended that I export from premiere to my local machine, then upload to youtube through the web interface.  The trouble is, I don't have my company's YouTube password.  I'm on a company workstation which knows the password and should be able to upload, but I don't know it myself.

Comment: No need to upload directly to youtube. Just export an mp4 file from Premiere (and wait only once for that hour) and THEN try to upload to youtube via the youtube web page. If something is wrong then just rename the file or re-write the description. No need to render again

Comment: Can you just upload with no description and then add it?

Comment: @Mulvya @ kazanaki I'm on a company workstation where I don't know the youtube password.  Premiere knows it, not me.  I could ask my boss to change the description, but it'd be better for everyone if it just worked right in the first place.

Comment: It could be that the Premiere script is post-processing the description and introducing some illegal characters. To eliminate that possibility, upload a very short video with no description and one with just a couple of characters.

Comment: @Mulvya Good idea.  I'll try that after this hour is up.

Comment: What did you find out?

Answer (score 1):

Just export as a .mp4, and then upload it to Youtube! Simple as that! Also, I think the "directly uploading" features just make it more confusing. Hope this helps!

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, I don't have the company password to upload to youtube directly.  I'll edit the question to mention this.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. I think asking your boss the password to the Youtube channel might be the easiest solution.

Comment: You're right, that would be an easy practical solution.  But the company I work for is large enough that giving the keys to its public perception to a single editor is a bad idea.  Also, I don't *want* to be liable for any unapproved video or text.

Comment: Hmmm... then I'm not really sure... I wish I could help. Maybe you could try going onto the Youtube forums. I am not really sure... :(